# Is worksheet.Buttons() a extension method?

Tags: excel, vba, button

When we work with controls in VBA. *(For simplicity, let sht represent a worksheet object)*
We normally do sht.Shapes(xxx) or sht.OLEObjects(xxx) to access controls. Shapes() and OLEObjects() are well defined in the documentation. They are properties of the worksheet object.

However, sht.Buttons(xxx), sht.CheckBoxes(xxx) actually also work. But they are not defined in the document. If you check the object library in the VBE, you still can't find them. And if you type things in VBE, no IntelliSense for .Buttons of .CheckBoxes, but there're IntelliSense for .Shapes()

Even though you can access a button using sht.Buttons() and sht.Shapes(), however, I find sht.Buttons() return an object with a much cleaner interface.

So where are the .Buttons method from? Is it just an extension method defined somewhere for the worksheet object?

Comment: Side note: right-click in the Object Browser and click Show Hidden Members. You'll see `Buttons` and `CheckBoxes` under the `Worksheet` object.

Comment: @BigBen thanks mate! that makes perfect sense then.  Just curious why Microsoft make Buttons hidden member. don't understand.